# Trouble adding post-self-insert-hook in define-minor-mode

Tags: hooks, minor-mode

I am trying to write a minor mode that upon visiting a word, it manipulate it. There is a list of words which is parsed from a file. Here is the problem:

```
(define-minor-mode auto-gls-mode
  "Documentation goes here"
  :lighter " AGLS"
  ;(setq agls-list '("foo" "bar"))    <----------works
  (setq agls-list (agls-parse-acn-file)) <-------doesn't work
  (if auto-gls-mode
      (add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook
        'agls-check-word nil t)
    (remove-hook 'post-self-insert-hook
         'agls-check-word t)))
```

and the hooked function:

```
(defun agls-check-word ()
  "Check if the word is in the list"
  (if (= last-command-event 32)
      (do-some-stuff)))
```

The `agls-parse-acn-file` is pretty long but in pseudo-elisp reads like this:

```
(defun agls-parse-acn-file()
  ;find-file-noselect
  ;while new-line
    ;extract keywords
    ;end
  local-list)
```

simply opens a file by `find-file-noselect`, parse it, extract keywords and return a list. The conundrum is that, if populate the list as pointed by arrow the function in `add-hook` get called properly. If I use populate the list by calling the parse function, as I type in buffers with minor mode activate, nothing happens (`agls-check-word` is not called)

Comment: I don't understand what's the trouble in the question title. Does `(agls-parse-acn-file)` work? If `agls-list` doesn't change, you don't need to set its value every time the mode is turned on and off.

Comment: @xuchunyang, thanks for reply. The function you mentioned does work. The `agls-list` gets populated, however, when I activate the minor mode and type in buffer, `agls-check-word` function which is added to hook does *not* get called. If I use the comment line and set the list in the body of `define-minor-mode` and comment the call to `agls-parse-acn-file`, then everything goes fine.

Comment: You can use `C-h v post-self-insert-hook` to see if `agls-check-word` is added. Maybe during `agls-parse-acn-file` you change the current buffer? We usually use `(with-temp-buffer (insert-file-contents "path/to/file") (parse-the-file))` to read a file, instead of `find-file-noselect`

Comment: @xuchunyang thanks a lot! That was exactly the problem. If you turn your comment into an answer I will gladly accept it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the comments, you changed the current buffer during `agls-parse-acn-file`, you can use the following instead:

```el
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert-file-contents "path/to/file")
  (parse-the-file))
```